# Applications and files no longer showing in Windows 7 search

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

As of a few days ago the "Search Programs and Files" accessible via the Start button stopped functioning.  If I type in a program name or file details I do not get any 'proper' results.  What simply appears are 3 items -- Programs, Documents, Files.  Each item appears to have the icon that is bound to the 'no extension' file format (in my case a green box).

If I click on any of these items to open it it errors saying that the file can't be opened due to Internet security settings.  If I right-click and ask top open the containing folder it takes me to my desktop folder but there is no file there (have checked for hidden/system files too).

If I click "See more results" this finds the files as per usual.

I am unsure what triggered this, I have tried re-indexing Search and even removing Search and re-installing that feature.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Microsoft Support article deals with the problem:

[The "Search programs and files" box does not display search results correctly in Windows 7 and in Windows 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977380)

It offers a hotfix that you can download, or the following manual method:

> 1. Press the Windows logo key + R on your keyboard.
> 2. In the Run box, type regedit and then press ENTER.
>    If you are
>      prompted for an administrator password
>      or for confirmation, type the password
>      or provide confirmation.
> 3. Locate the following registry subkey:
>      
>    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6}`
> 4. Right-click this subkey, and then select Delete.
> 5. Restart the computer.

Take the usual precautions before editing the registry, such as creating a system restore point.